# MATLAB - plot an iteration

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The code so far:

```
function [fr]=frictionFactorFn(rho,mu,e,D,L,Q,f0,tol,imax)
format long
CS=(pi*D^(2))/4;%Cross sectional area of pipe
v=Q/CS;%velocity
Re=(rho*v*L)/mu;
iter=1;i=1;fr(1)=f0;
while 1
fr(i+1)=(-1.74*log((1.254/(Re*sqrt(fr(i))))+((e/D)/3.708)))^-2;%substitution for root finding
iter=iter+1;
if abs(fr(i+1)-fr(i))<tol || iter>=imax
break;
end
i=i+1;
end
fprintf('\n The Reynolds number is %f\n',Re);
plot(0:iter-1,fr);
xlabel('Number of iteration'),ylabel('friction factor');
end
```

It gave me the right converged value of `f=0.005408015`, but I would like to plot the iteration

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: The complete problem description is posted by the OP in his [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66229895/5698672)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly by storing the values of `f` upon each iteration in an array. In this example the array is called `Store_f` and is plotted after the while-loop is completed. The variable `Index` below is used to indicate which cell of array `Store_f` the value should be saved to.

[image: Plotting Function]

```
function [f_vals] = frictionfactorfn()

Index = 1;

    while (Condition)
    %Calculation code%

        Store_f(Index) = f;
        Index = Index + 1;
    end

    disp(num2str(f))
    plot(Store_f,'Marker','.');
    xlabel('Iteration'); ylabel('Value');
end
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help. `'Marker','.'` adds the little data point dots, you can remove it if you don't need the dots or change them to a variety of different symbols such as `*` or `x`.